# Effective way to find duplicate values and sum up via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20,000 rows and 34 columns in spreadsheet. I need to sum up the two  duplicates column values, if the columns are equal and delete the remainig duplicate rows except the first one and need to sort the column E in descending order before deleting the rows.
 It takes 4 minutes to do the entire process. Is there any other effective way to do this, regards to performance?

```
A(car)    B(model)     C(Num plate)     D(Country)      E(Price)      F(Tax)
1.BMW         E309           D345            Germany      456778        6733
2.BMW         E309           D345           India         456737        8643
3.Audi        Q5             H54            Austria        98833        3333
4.Benz        A34            F45            Belgium        33333         9933
5.Audi        Q5             H54            Italy          8833        13333
```

Result:

```
A(car)    B(model)     C(Num plate)     D(Country)      E(Price)      F(Tax)
1.BMW      E309           D345          Germany         913515        15376
2.Audi      Q5             H54          Austria         107666        16666
```

Code:

```
Sub Vba()

Dim Master_workbook As Workbook
Dim Ws2_Lrow As Long
Dim Ws2_Lcol As Long
Dim rngFilter_Ws2 As Range

With Master_workbook.Worksheets("Portal")

Master_workbook.Worksheets("Portal").Activate

Ws2_Lrow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
            Ws2_Lcol = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            Set rngFilter_Ws2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Ws2_Lrow, Ws2_Lcol))


 Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom


         'delete duplicate rows and sum up the values of respective column

            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                'step off the header and make one column wider
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Offset(1, 0)
                         .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(E:E, A:A, A2, B:B, B2, C:C, C2)"
                         .Columns(5) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
                         .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(F:F, A:A, A2, B:B, B2, C:C, C2)"
                         .Columns(6) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
                         .Columns(.Columns.Count).Delete
                    End With

                'remove duplicates
                    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
             End With
End sub
```

can someone please help me out.

Comment: your result table does not summarize your original table correctly, as the country column is still in the result table. I think what you are trying to do will confuse your report user. :)

If you ignore the potential confusion, one way to do this is to construct a dictionary (refer to Scripting.dictionary) with key of Column A + Column B.

Comment: @Danielle The country column must be in there in result table. It should be sum up columns(E,F) based on the columns(A,B,C).

Answer (score 0):

The following way results in a lot more (automatically generated) code, but should be reasonable faster, because it´s using the built-in pivot-table functionality:

1. Activate Macro recording
2. Select the columns with your data
3. Goto "Insert - Pivottable" and accept default-settings
4. Drop columns A, B and C into "Row Labels"
5. Drop columns E and F into "Values"
6. set "Value Field Settings" to "SUM"
7. remove Subtotals for A, B, C
8. select the resulting data-cells
9. copy them to clipboard
10. goto to desired destination cell
11. paste from clipboard
12. stop macro-recording

Based on that code (which is obviously worth to refine), you can replay these steps anytime you like.